# Draw a rectangle with center as touch point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch

I am working on a project in which I have to create a tagging screen.What exactly I have to do is when the user touch on the image a rectangle should be drawn assuming the center points be the touch points.Please suggest me the approach or some sample code which I should follow it.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this but I prefer the idea of using layers for this task. For this to work, you will have to attach a tap recognizer to the image view and add the tag layers as sublayers to the image view's layer in the gesture handler.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[imageView addGesture:tap];
[tap release];

...

- (void)handleGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    CALayer *newLayer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.bounds = layerBounds;
    layer.position = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    layer.backgroundColor = layerBackgroundColor;

    [imageView.layer addSublayer:layer];
}
```

You will have to add the `QuartzCore` framework for this to work and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

you could change the **center** point of an [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW3) using center point property ,

Change `center` property of your view and redraw it.

Comment: can u please tell me how to do a rectanle using center as current touch point.